# Sitecore Item not working on Normal Mode but working on preview mode

Tags: sitecore

In one of my current project,result coming in preview mode but not coming in normal mode.

Work that i have already done:

1. Done full published.
2. item available on web database and master
3. database both. Working fine on dev environment.
4. issue related with
5. UAT enrionment only.
6. currently using jquery and solr search for displaying result.

I have researched a lot for this issue,i would highly  appreciate for valuable feedback.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you check whether the item has a unique name (i.e. not another item with the same name in the same level of the tree)
Do you mean it's not showing up in the indexes or do you mean when you browse to it it doesn't display?

Comment: Can you share your code that search for results?

Comment: the result is coming by query,but not showing on web,i am hitting web index,item is already indexed in web.

Answer (score 1):

Your saying that the item is in the web database, but you're using solr for displaying results.

Check if the item is in the Solr web index.

E.g. by using the url:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/itembuckets/select?q=(_fullpath:"/sitecore/content/full/path/to/your/item")&rows=10&fq=_indexname:sitecore_web_index`

Replace:

1. `localhost` and `8983` with location of your Solr server location,
2. `itembuckets` with the name of your Solr core,
3. `sitecore_web_index` with the name of your index
4. `/sitecore/content/full/path/to/your/item` with a path of your item.

If the item is not there it means that is not included in the index. Most probably database was restored from Live to UAT, but index was not rebuilt, so database and index are out of sync.

You need to add this item to the index or just execute full web index rebuilt from the Sitecore `Control Panel`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing,but it was the basic thing to check solr query,the result is already coming by query but not in frontend.

Comment: Is the item in the response from your jquery call to solr? You can use fiddler or firebug or other similar tools to see exactly what is the query and what is the response.